# How to display image in mail body from database using yii2 framework

Tags: mysql, cron, yii2

How to display image in mail body from database with yii2 framework?

With the following code, we could run through directory path but could not display the image.

```
<img src= 'Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/photo/default.png')'>
```

Comment: Try `<img src= <?= Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/photo/default.png') ?>>`

Comment: @InsaneSkull  same result. not displaying the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<img src= <?= Yii::app->request->hostName.'/photo/default.png') ?>>`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it